# number_to_human without rounding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My goal is to create human readable price tag from integer price.
For an example, price is 4_995_000, I want to get $4.99M.

I did try all of the options from [number_to_human](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human)

`number_to_human(4_995_000, format: "%n%u", units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }, significant: false, precision: 2)`

Result is `$5M`

I tried to use round mode also, but no luck with that.

I can only achieve 4.99 with precision 3 which I don't want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it it not really documented in the Rails documentation, you can pass the `round_mode` option and set it to `half_down`:

```
$ rails c
> helper.number_to_human(4_995_000, format: "%n%u", units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }, significant: false, precision: 2) 
#=> 5M
> helper.number_to_human(4_995_000, format: "%n%u", units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }, significant: false, precision: 2, round_mode: :half_down) 
#=> "4.99M"
> helper.number_to_human(4_996_000, format: "%n%u", units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }, significant: false, precision: 2, round_mode: :half_down) 
#=> "5M"
> helper.number_to_human(4_996_000, format: "%n%u", units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M' }, significant: false, precision: 2, round_mode: :down)
#=> "4.99M"
```

Here's a screenshot from the rails console:

[image: Screenshot from the rails console]

Comment: Not sure how do you get 4,99, it is returning 5M for me. I copy pasted your command, not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Which command did you copy-paste? Which version of ruby and rails are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ruby 2.7 and Rails 6.0. and I tried all of your commands and all of them are returning 5M. 

And then I tried on different machine with Ruby 3.0 and Rails 6.1 and it works...It is returning 4.99..

Comment: So, You are right, I will accept your answer, but do you know why is that a problem and is there a workaround?

Comment: @BBBB this option was introduced in [Rails 6.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb). If you look at the source code, you can see that option in Rails 6.1, but it is not there in [Rails 6.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb)